using multiple statements in switch expression is giving CS0201 error
Below C# switch expression is giving Compiler Error

CS0201 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Not sure what is wrong here?
In this case need to add multiple statements for each case.
status switch
{
    "ANY" => () =>
    {
        checkboxUtils.TickCheckbox(name, status);
        return;
    }
    ,
    "true" => () =>
    {
        if (!(bool)ChecksCkeckboxIsChecked(name, status))
            checkboxUtils.TickCheckbox(name, status);
    }
    ,
    "false" => () =>
    {
        if ((bool)ChecksCkeckboxIsChecked(name, status))
            checkboxUtils.TickCheckbox(name, status);
    }
    ,
    _ => () =>
    {
        DriverContext.Driver.Wait(1);
        checkboxUtils.TickCheckbox(name, status);
        DriverContext.Driver.Wait(2);

        if (!(bool)ChecksCkeckboxIsChecked(name, status))
        {
            testUtilsSteps.ThenUserRefreshesThePage();
            continue;
        }
    }
};


Can you post the full error message, for those of us who haven't memorised what error "CS0201" is?

Why are you using a switch expression? It sounds like you want to use a switch statement instead. What you're doing is abusing the switch expression feature.

The switch expression returns a value whereas the switch statement executes statements.

Does this answer your question? Using blocks in C# switch expression?

I know I brought up this post in my previous comment, but I don't think it's a duplicate. In the other post, the OP acknowledges that the switch expression could be (better) rewritten using a switch statement of if's - the question is explicitly about making it work with expressions. In this post, I feel the OP doesn't understand the difference between statements and expressions, and them using expressions is an X/Y problem. Closing as a duplicate doesn't express that they're using the wrong tool.

You're using a switch expression. The switch must return a value (and be assigned to something), hence your error.
Don't use them, it's wholly inappropriate for your use case. Instead, use a switch statement.
switch (status)
{
    case "ANY":
        checkboxUtils.TickCheckbox(name, status);
        return;
    case "true":
        if (!(bool)ChecksCkeckboxIsChecked(name, status))
            checkboxUtils.TickCheckbox(name, status);
        break;
    // ... the rest
}

The only reason you'd want to use a switch expression is if you were creating an Action variable to execute later. In order to do that you'd need to

You must assign the value of the switch expression to a variable (Action action = status switch { ...)
Each "case" in your switch must return the same type. It looks like you're doing a void Action. This means you cannot use the continue keyword, and return simply means to return early from the anonymous function, not the outer context.

Really, don't try to hack using switch expressions, use the right tool for this job.

thanks @gun2171, now I get it. Will use switch statement.
